# SonarQube page extension with html possible?

Tags: sonarqube

I just read about extending SonarQube with custom pages. All examples I have found consist only of javascript files.

Is it possible to have html files as well or is it javascript only? If it is javascript only then the whole feature is completely useless as nobody wants to create all the html elements with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's Javascript only.

However, there's [a guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Implement+Pages+with+React) on how to use React to create the HTML elements, which makes it a lot more bearable. Try it!